# Ajax get call to populate array variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, tag-it

I'm using Jquery Tagit.

It provides an option "AvailableTags" which accepts an array of items to populate the AutoComplete.

My ajax get call does not seem to be working when I pass the received array to the Tagit call even though it seems to be generating the appropriate data (filled array) that I need.

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
type: 'get',
url: 'gettags.php',
data: "",
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
sampleTags = data;
}
})

$('#singleFieldTags').tagit({
availableTags: sampleTags,
singleField: true,
singleFieldNode: $('#mySingleField'),
allowSpaces: true
});
```

PHP

```
$sql = "SELECT tag FROM tags"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$data = array[];

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
$data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

I'm simply trying to pass the returned array to Tagit's "availableTags" via the variable sampleTags, but it doesn't seem to want to carry over.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

`$.ajax()` is executed asynchronously, so you need to process the data right in the `success` callback:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'gettags.php',
    data: "",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var sampleTags = data;
        $('#singleFieldTags').tagit({
            availableTags: sampleTags,
            singleField: true,
            singleFieldNode: $('#mySingleField'),
            allowSpaces: true
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Actually I screwed up there... .html("Data") was not supposed to be there. I need to pass the sampleTags array.

Comment: $('#singleFieldTags').tag accepts availableTags: (array) to populate AutoComplete... my ajax call get the tags from the DB via sampleTags = data. I want that sampleTags to be available to availableTags.

Comment: @blue-eye: look at my code and do in the same way - `sampleTags` is **only** available in the `success` callback

Comment: Ok, I see where I was going wrong... it's not available later on so I need to do it together all in the one call. Unfortunately the code that was included $('#singleFieldTags') needs to be outside the function or the autocomplete is not called on each keypress. The goal was only to have to run the query once to get the array of available tags, so that it doesn't run a query on each keypress.

Comment: @blue-eye: well, it's only available there

Answer (score 1):

My function was in an external JS file. By moving the code back into the same file I was able to do a simple php include to get what I wanted.

```
$('#singleFieldTags').tagit({ 
availableTags: <? include("file_that_outputs_what_I_want.php") ?>,  
singleField: true, 
singleFieldNode: $('#mySingleField'), 
allowSpaces: true 
});
```